# Recursive Merge sort in java

Tags: java, recursion, merge, queue, mergesort

I have been studying on merge sort as algorithm and visualization. When I went through the coding part, it was kinda challenging for me. But, I still did the coding with a runtime error. The error is **NullPointerException**. Please help me. It's a school project.

```
public class test
{       
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {               
        int arr[]={11,34,65,89,1,456,90,85,12,70};
        mergesort(arr,0,9);
        for(int a=0;a<arr.length;a++)
            System.out.println(arr[a]);
    }

    public static void mergesort (int arr[], int low, int high)
    {           
        int middle;
        if(low<high)
        {
        middle = (low+high)/2;
        mergesort(arr,low,middle);
        mergesort(arr,middle+1,high);
        merge(arr,low,middle,high);
        }           
    }

    public static void merge(int arr[], int low, int middle, int high)
    {
        Queue<Integer> buffer1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();     
        Queue<Integer> buffer2 = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
        int i;

        for(int a=low;a<middle;a++) buffer1.add(arr[a]);
        for(int a=middle+1;a<high;a++) buffer2.add(arr[a]);
        i=low;
        while(!(buffer1.isEmpty()) && !(buffer2.isEmpty()))
        {
            if(buffer1.peek() <= buffer2.peek())
            {
                arr[i] = buffer1.poll();

            } else
            {
                arr[i] = buffer2.poll();                    
            }               
        }
        while(!(buffer1.isEmpty()))
        {
            arr[i] = buffer1.poll();
        }
        while(!(buffer2.isEmpty()))
        {
            arr[i] = buffer2.poll();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the stacktrace has to say.. which line etc? Can you highlight that particular line in code above?

Comment: You say null pointer exception so can you paste the whole part from log. it will say it occured at line number XXX so which line is it from above code.

Comment: i updated the code. it contains the full implementation. the error is in line 18. it is in recursion part.

Comment: which is line 18 please? Can you highlight it in code?

Comment: Why do you have a semicolon after while expression

Comment: @AbdullaDlshad  What does the error line say? And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Steve this code has no compilation error. it does not sort the integers correctly.

Comment: @AbdullaDlshad How does it sort them, then, can you include your test cases and outputs as well?

Comment: @Steve it sorts them recursively. i think it sorts only the 1st half. 
11
12
65
89
1
456
90
85
12
70


this is the output of the program.

Comment: @AbdullaDlshad You are not incrementing your 'i' !

Comment: @Steve can you post the code with incremented i??

Comment: @AbdullaDlshad  Okay let me debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the updated code which is running OK with no compilation and run-time error:

```
public class Merge 
{

public static void mergesort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int middle;
    if(low<high)
    {
        middle = (low+high)/2;
        mergesort(arr,low,middle);
        mergesort(arr,middle+1,high);
        merge(arr,low,middle,high);
    }
}
public static void merge(int arr[], int low, int middle, int high)
{
    Queue<Integer>half1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Queue<Integer>half2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    for(int j = low; j<=middle;j++)
        {               
            half1.add(arr[j]);
        }
    for(int j= middle+1 ; j<=high ; j++)
        {
            half2.add(arr[j]);
        }
    int i = low;
    while(!(half1.isEmpty() || half2.isEmpty()))
    {
        if(half1.peek() <= half2.peek())
        {
            arr[i++] = half1.poll();

        }
        else {arr[i++] = half2.poll();}
    }

    while(!half1.isEmpty())
    {
        arr[i++] = half1.poll();
    }
    while(!half2.isEmpty())
    {
        arr[i++] = half2.poll();
    }
}

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
         int arr[] = {11,45,90,121,67,19,54,28,7,50}; 
         mergesort(arr,0,arr.length-1);

         for(int a=0;a<arr.length;a++)
              System.out.println(arr[a]);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loops like this

```
for(i=low;i<=middle;i++)
{
    buffer1.add(arr[i]);                
}
for(i=middle+1;i<=high;i++)
{
    buffer2.add(arr[i]);
}
```

Here *low* and *high* denote the index of *first* and *last* elements of array.

Comment: so, the only difference is that you added equal to the conditions right?

Comment: still not working. the problem is in the calling in main method.
it gives NullPointerException run-time error..